# Composition of analytic function

Tags: complex-analysis

Given $g(z)=\sqrt r e^{i\theta/2}$, $(r>0,-\pi<\theta<\pi)$ is analytic in its domain of definition, show that the function $G(z) = g(2z-2+i)$ is analytic in the half plane $x>1$.

My question, Why is $G(z)$ analytic in the half plane $x>1$? Isn't $G(z)$ analytic on any $z\in \mathbb{C}$ such that $2z-2+i\neq 0$?

Edit, I misread the domain. It does not include $z\in \mathbb{C}$ with $\arg(z)=\pi$.

Comment: $\{z \in \mathbb C : \mathrm{Re}[z] > 1\} \subseteq \{z \in \mathbb C: G \textrm{ is analytic at } z\}$, so the statement seems to be true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. It's analytic on$$\{z\in\mathbb{C}\,|\,2z-2+i\notin(-\infty,0]\}.$$

Comment: Does the set contains complex numbers $z$ with Re$z$ $\leq 0$ , Img$z$ $\neq 0$?

Comment: @LittleRookie Sure. It contains $-1+i$, for instance.